# Inno Setup dir failure and launch failure

Tags: inno-setup

I'm having some issues with Inno Setup.

1: The 'Dirs' fail to create but no error is logged.

2: The application fails to run after install and the check box option does not appear in any of the set-up pages.

Inno script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=TestApp™
AppVersion=1.0.0.0
AppId={{3334B489-80D3-4741-87F2-17699CCDDDAC}
ChangesAssociations=yes
SetupIconFile=userdocs:Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\res\Icons\2001.ico
ShowLanguageDialog=no
UninstallDisplayName=TestApp
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\TestApp.exe
VersionInfoVersion=1.0.0.0
VersionInfoCompany=MyCompany™
VersionInfoDescription=Test App
VersionInfoCopyright=© 2015 MyCompany™
VersionInfoProductName=TestApp™
VersionInfoProductVersion=1.0.0.0
SolidCompression=True
Compression=lzma2/ultra
InternalCompressLevel=ultra
MinVersion=0,5.01
DefaultDirName={pf}\TestApp
DefaultGroupName=TestApp
LicenseFile=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\EULA.txt
OutputBaseFilename=TestApp v1
WizardImageBackColor=$00FF6633
AppCopyright=© 2015 MyCompany™
AppPublisher=MyCompany™
DisableStartupPrompt=False
UninstallDisplaySize=5000000
AlwaysShowGroupOnReadyPage=True
AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage=True

[Dirs]
Name: "{localappdata}\TestApp";
Name: "{localappdata}\TestApp\Files";

[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".myext"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "TestApp"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "TestApp\Content Type"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "application/x-myext"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "TestApp\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\TestApp.EXE"",0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "TestApp\shell"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "open"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "TestApp\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\TestApp.EXE"" ""%1"""

[Files]
Source: "Build\TestApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\TestApp.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\EULA.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\TestApp"; Filename: "{app}\TestApp.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\TestApp.exe"; IconIndex: 0
Name: "{commondesktop}\TestApp"; Filename: "{app}\TestApp.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\"; IconIndex: 0

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\TestApp.EXE"; Description: "Launch application"; Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent unchecked

[ThirdParty]
CompileLogFile=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.log
```

Log file:

```
    Starting compile.  [Friday, March 20 2015 at 16:19:58]
    Compiling script with Inno Setup 5.5.5 (a) [ISDLLCompileScriptA]

    [PreCompile] Processing.
    [PreCompile] Processing is still being tested.
    [PreCompile] Processing finished.

    [ISPP] Preprocessing.
    [ISPP] Preprocessed.

    Parsing [Setup] section, line 2
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 3
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 4
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 5
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 6
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 7
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 8
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 9
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 10
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 11
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 12
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 13
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 14
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 15
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 16
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 17
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 18
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 19
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 20
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 21
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 23
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 24
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 25
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 26
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 27
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 28
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 29
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 30
    Parsing [Setup] section, line 31
    Reading file (LicenseFile)
    Reading file (WizardImageFile)
       File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\WIZMODERNIMAGE.BMP
    Reading file (WizardSmallImageFile)
       File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\WIZMODERNSMALLIMAGE.BMP
    Preparing Setup program executable
       Updating icons (SETUP.E32)
    Reading default messages from Default.isl
    Parsing [LangOptions], [Messages], and [CustomMessages] sections
       File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Default.isl
       Messages in script file
    Reading [Code] section
    Parsing [Dirs] section, line 34
    Parsing [Dirs] section, line 35
    Parsing [Icons] section, line 50
    Parsing [Icons] section, line 51
    Parsing [Registry] section, line 38
    Parsing [Registry] section, line 39
    Parsing [Registry] section, line 40
    Parsing [Registry] section, line 41
    Parsing [Registry] section, line 42
    Parsing [Run] section, line 54
    Parsing [Files] section, line 45
       Reading version info: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\TestApp.exe
    Parsing [Files] section, line 46
       Reading version info: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\TestApp.dll
    Parsing [Files] section, line 47
       Reading version info: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\EULA.txt
    Deleting TestApp v1.exe from output directory
    Creating setup files
       Updating icons (SETUP.EXE)
       Compressing: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\TestApp.exe   (5.0.0.0)
       Compressing: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\TestApp.dll   (3.2.0.5)
       Compressing: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestApp\Build\EULA.txt
       Compressing Setup program executable
       Updating version info

    [PostCompile] Processing.

[PostCompile] Processing is still being tested.
[PostCompile] Processing finished.

Compile finished.  [Friday, March 20 2015 at 16:20:01]
Total compile time: 00:03.547
```

As far as I can tell the code is as it should be from the manual so what is it I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have just compiled and executed your script and it worked fine (*except that I did not have the files of your VisualStudio-Path*). 
But more importantly, the Dirs were created! Are you sure they are not there? Perhaps you just need to refresh an explorer view - or maybe you looked at the wrong place (%LOCALAPPDATA% has the directories.)

Comment: Looking: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local on Win8 and C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data on XP but nothing there, tried various dir names also.

Comment: If you have an explorer-window, you can also paste %LOCALAPPDATA% in the box where it shows the path and that will be resolved to the actual value (which was also used by IS).- could you pls. check that?

Comment: %LOCALAPPDATA%, tried that and nothing (doesn't work on XP though)

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly does "nothing" mean?  Nothing happens , nothing installed there or...? Did it replace that with a valid path at least?

Comment: It means no directory was created

Comment: I'm using W7 and it worked, and I  have no idea why this should not work under W8. Perhaps one last thing: did you try some file-mgmnt-tool to see if a "TestApp"-dir was created ANYWHERE on your machine?